# Estimate the persistence length of a rubber band

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, continuum-mechanics, soft-matter

Not much more to say here, it's all in the question. The best, most convincing estimate will be chosen as the correct answer.

EDIT: Assume the rubber band is at room temperature, with thickness $t$ and width $w$, is linear (i.e. not circular), and was produced under standard factory conditions. What is the persistence length $P$ as a function of $w$ and $t$?

Comment: Note that there isn't actually a question here. There's a command and a few remarks. What type of conditions do you expect the rubber band to be in? Room temperature? Hotter? Colder? Can we assume a linear chain? Something else? Some clarifications are necessary.

Comment: You can specify any relevant parameters (temperature, width, thickness, etc) as variables; just assume it's a linear (i.e. not circular) rubber band at a solid temperature.

Comment: Then your question is what we would consider "too broad" to be answerable. Consider changing your question by including the necessary clarifications to receive an answer and to prevent closure (and downvotes).

Comment: Okay, I made the problem more quantitative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_length) the persistence length is estimated from

$$P = \frac{EI}{k_B T}$$

The second moment of area $a$ of a rectangular section with width $w$ and thickness $t$ is given by

$$I = \frac{t^3 w}{16}$$

The Young's modulus of rubber can be taken as `10 MPa` (although it varies a lot... we will ignore that and stick to the lower limit).  For a typical rubber band with `t=1 mm`, `w = 5 mm` we obtain $$P = 1.2\cdot 10^{16} \mathrm{m}$$

This is not inconsistent with the calculation that was given in the above link for a piece of spaghetti, for which they calculated $10^{18}\mathrm{m}$.